# Можно ли сказать «перекипячевывать»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

Можно ли **повторное кипячение** назвать одним словом и как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1):

ПЕРЕКИПЯТИ́ТЬ, перекипячу, перекипятишь, **совер.**, что. ***Вскипятить вновь. Перекипятить воду.***

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940

Формы инфинитива несовершенного вида со значением повторного кипячения, скорей всего, нет. Заменяем словосочетанием - кипятить повторно, кипятить ещё раз и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя, в качестве глагола несовершенного вида (видимо, вопрос поставлен о нём) можно рассматривать только вариант "**перекипячивать**", в значении повторного (многократного) кипячения, словарями не фиксируемый (на этом основании "грамота" отрицает его существование). Слово малоупотребительно, но по способу образования оно мало чем отличается от распространённого *выпячивать* (выпятить).

Слово встречается в книгах нескольких современных литераторов (Юрий Райн, 2017; Дмитрий Старицкий, 2017; Александр Тюрин и др., 2018, В. Сидур, 2002) и у одного классика (В. Г. Короленко, Бытовые очерки, "Крымский вестник", №182).

По типу словообразования предложенный в вопросе вариант чужероден глаголу совершенного вида "перекипятить", ср. *выкорчевать - выкорчёвывать*.

Comment: А существование древнерусского языка до появления первых словарей Грамота не отрицает? Странная позиция.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать глагол [перекипяти́ть](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/210774/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) (о нем уже сказала @Екатерина Каштанова) и, как мне кажется, можно в некоторых случаях  употребить глагол [**подкипяти́ть**](https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-slovo/1148800.html) (*сов. перех. разг.*, покипятить дополнительно).

В словаре [Даля](http://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=13217):
**кипятить** *что*...  Подкипятить, подогреть. Перекипятить снова или черезчур.

*Дома она снова **подкипятила** самовар и уложила яйца. Но не прошло и двух минуток, она совершенно случайно махнула рукой, — кран открылся, и из самовара похлестал кипяток.*
П. Крупеников. Яйца для котлонадзора

Answer (score 0):

Повторное кипячение можно назвать одним словом — **перекипятить.**

**Из словаря Кузнецова на Грамоте-ру**

ПЕРЕКИПЯТИТЬ, -св. что. 1. Вскипятить **заново, ещё раз**. П. суп, бульон. П. бельё.

**Примечание**

Приставка ПЕРЕ многозначная, поэтому надо различать: (1) переделать что-то заново и (2) переделать все дела.

― Всё белье **перекипятил**, ― сказал он. ― Все-таки она придет после такой сложной хирургии. [Галина Щербакова.
(1997)]

В четверг он проснулся в четверть второго, **перекипятил** начавший скисать мясной бульон ... [Владимир Корнилов.  (1969-1971)]